# Perl: Copying files without knowing the prefix

Tags: perl, file

I have the path to a directory with one file. However, I don't know the prefix of the file meaning I only know the extension. How do I indicate this file in the path for the following code.

```
for (my $k = 1; $k < 21; $k++)
{
    my $best = "best";
    my $underscore = "_";
    my $best = "$best$underscore$k.bgf";
    my $alabest = "$best$underscore$k.ala.bgf";
    my $source1 = "$name/$interhelical/$cnti/$multidock/$best";
    my $source2 = "$name/$interhelical/$cnti/$multidock/$alabest";
    my $source3 = "$name/$interhelical/$cnti/$multidock/$spheres/$sph1/$sph2/*.sph";
    my $target = "some path";
    copy $source1 => $target;
}
```

I don't know the name of the file in the sph2 directory but I want to be able to indicate it in the path regardless of the prefix. Could you help me out?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use just `my $best = "best_$k.bgf"`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write something like

```
my @bgf = glob "$name/$interhelical/$cnti/$multidock/*.bgf"
```

then the array `@bgf` will contain *all* files ending with `.bgf` in that directory.

If you are correct about *"I have the path to a directory with one file"* then the array will have just a single element.

But your question is very unclear. What is `$source3`? Do you also need to be looking for `.bgf` files in the `spheres` directory? And why do you have variables for each separate segment of the path? If you have been given a simple path as you say, then it would be much better to write

```
my $bgf_path = 'name/interhelical/cnti/multidock';
my @bgf = glob "$bgf_path/*.bgf";
```

And that assumes that `$name`, `$interhelical` etc. contain the strings `name`, `interhelical` in the same way as `$best` holds `best`.

Answer (score 0):

Perls [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) is your friend in these circumstances.